# Display a customized Usr field in the Acumatica Mobile App

Tags: acumatica

I have created a new customized Usr field and I am attempting to make it visible in the mobile app.

The field is being added in the Task page (CR306020).
The field is a string value, added in the Details tab of the page:
[image: Task with Cust Field]

Then, the Mobile Application node of the customization project is modified to add the new field:

```
update screen CR306020 {
  update container "Details"{
  add field "UsrMobileApp"{
  placeAfter field "DueDate"
  }
}
}
```

This field is correctly visible in the Result Preview section:
[image: Result Preview]

However, the field is not visible in the Mobile App.

I reviewed the Service Description of the page, and noticed that the new Usr field is not visible there, which seems to explain why it's not visible in the App

I tried to make it visible in the Service Description by going to the WebServices page (SM207040). A New web service was added, and the Task page was added to the grid, and then the GENERATE button was pressed. But the field is still not visible in the Service Description section.

Any idea what could I be missing?
Note: I attempted to use the field without the Usr prefix, but the result is the same.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you let us know how you created this field? Like what you put in the customization project in order to add that field to the screen. Could you also post somewhere the service definition so we can take a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I reviewed the Service Description of the page, and noticed that the new Usr field 
is not visible there, which seems to explain why it's not visible in the App.
```

That's the most common explanation. Make sure the custom field is visible on screen and it should appear in the `Service Description` accessible with `Help->Web Service`.

Comment: Thanks @HB_Acumatica. The field is visible on the screen. In the Details tab - under the Completion % field. I restarted the application. But the field does not appear in the page's Service Description

Comment: Web service description uses DisplayName for field names. From your screenshot the display name of your custom field seems to be CustomizedField. Are you sure you don't have a field named CustomizedField in the web service description? Can you add the full web service description to your answer?

Comment: That was the solution @HB_Acumatica. Thanks much for the help!